# Cordova build for android issue

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js

I am using vue-cordova to wrap cordova into my Vue.js.

I added android platform, I could build and get apk.

The challenge I'm having right now that after days of development, when I run `cordova build android` the apk that gets generated only reflects the application as at 27th of March. Every line of code from then on to date is ignored.

Anyone know what could be problem?

Answer (score 0):

As information is very limited in your question so try below:

`npm install`

`sudo cordova prepare`

and then

`cordova build android`

Comment: Sorry for late response. I seem to be getting same result. What information would help to troubleshoot?